# WebViewDidFinishLoad executes after window.onload

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

iOS code webViewDidFinishLoad after JS code window.onload

In iOS webViewDidFinishLoad delegate

I do

```
self.jsContext = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];

     self.jsContext[@"enterplorer_home"] = self;
```

In local HTML webView. I have downloaded the HTML.

```
window.onload = function(){
         ....
        var userInfo = enterplorer_home.getInfo()?JSON.parse(enterplorer_home.getInfo()):{};
         .....

}
```

I debugged in the Safari console.

An error show me:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: enterplorer_home

Why is the iOS webViewDidFinishLoad execute too late?

What can I do to set the `enterplorer_home` before the `window.onload` execute.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly you are working on, but one solution is to wrap a requestAnimationFrame and execute the things inside onload there:

```
window.onload = function(){
    (function execute(){
        if (window.enterplorer_home) {
            ....
            var userInfo = enterplorer_home.getInfo()?JSON.parse(enterplorer_home.getInfo()):{};
            .....
        } else {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(execute);
        }
    })()
}
```